# Extracting Authorization code from AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want to extract authorization code from B2C but without log in to it, is that possible?

I am looking to get tokens for Alexa skill linking without requiring a user to be present

With what exactly I have a problem:

[Account linking issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f20d8.png)

1. can the backend of app ask for an authorization code from B2C directly without login screen ?
2. What do they mean in the diagram by "your's app backend Server"

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't really make sense, the authorization code is sent in response to a login (to acquire a set of tokens that are actually used to identify the user and authorize access to resources).

What problem are you trying to solve? 

For example, do you want to gain tokens to authorize resources (e.g. APIs) without requiring a user to be present? Or are you looking to sign a user in without having to go through the B2C UI?

Comment: Hello Dave D, thank you for your answer, sorry for not describing my question more clearly. 
Yes I am looking to get tokens for Alexa skill linking without requiring a user to be present. As far as I understood I need to extract Authorization code, than use that code to gain access token.  I will edit my question and insert a picture for more detail problem.

Answer (score 1):

As @DaveD answered, you get an authorisation code using the [authorisation code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow) and for that, you have to log in.

If you don't want to log on, you can use [client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) but that does not have an authorisation code. B2C does not currently support this.

If you don't want to log on, you can use [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-custom-policy) but that does not have an authorisation code.

Perhaps you are rather looking to acquire an access token?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [your attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f20d8.png) I don't think the interaction here is to do with B2C, it's all to do with Amazon.

The sequence diagram shows an app interacting with Amazon/Alexa, effectively to perform a login and retrieve an `authorization_code`. The code is coming from Amazon/Alexa, not from B2C.

It's showing that a backend app should receive that `authorization_code` then exchange it with Amazon for a set of tokens, i.e. an `access_token` allowing you to access the Alexa Service, and a `refresh_token` so you can refesh that `access_token` when it expires without requiring additional user input.

The `authorization_code` that the diagram is telling you to retrieve is that `authorization_code` originally returned from Amazon/Alexa. It's the same one that you used to acquire the `access_token` and `refresh_token` (at least by my understanding of what's presented solely in the diagram).

The backend server in the diagram is your app's backend server, it's where your code is that handles user authentications, interacts with databases and caches, that kind of thing. What exactly the backend server is in your case will depend on the architecture of your particular solution, there isn't necessarily an easy answer to this.

The only part of the diagram that would be handled by B2C is the very first two steps where the user logs in and has a token returned. However, the diagram assumes that that login is handled by your app, it's not showing authentication against some external token service like B2C, so it's important to understand that "backend server" here is *not* B2C.